# Is the response object passed to the receiving resource when doing server.transfer?

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page(SEO.aspx), which receives a SEO friendly url, processes it and then transfers the control to the relevant aspx page, using server.transfer.

Now, based on certain conditions, I want to set a cookie value in the SEO.aspx and then transfer the control to the relevant aspx page.

So in my SEO.aspx

```
HttpCookie NewVer = new HttpCookie("newver", "true");
Response.Cookies.Add(NewVer);
```

But I am not sure if this will be available in the final response or not. I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx but it does not specify anything about the response object.

What is the expected behavior?

Comment: The document you have linked to is for _classic_ asp. You have tagged your question as ASP.NET. Which is it?

Comment: @Oded - Server.Transfer is not just Classic asp, but .NET Framework also - so his question is relevant regardless no?

Comment: @David - Not about relevance. But The link is completely wrong for the question. It is documentation for the _wrong_ `Transfer`.

Comment: @Oded - Searching on msdn for Server.Transfer leads to that link only. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=server.transfer&ac=2

Comment: Better not post a misleading link then.

Comment: @oded Thanks for pointing to the correct link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it Server.Transfer transfers request execution from one resource to another. So if you have code executing on your SEO.aspx before you call Server.Transfer("SomeOtherPage.aspx") then that code will be run before the SomeOtherPage.aspx resource is executed.

This is easily tested by looking for the cookie - For example using Firefox, Install FireBug (http://getfirebug.com/) and FireCookie (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/) and replicate your test conditions - FireCookie will show you whether or not the cookie was planted in the browser.

Comment: So the response object is passed after all!

Comment: Worth noting about the `Request.Cookies` collection however: After modifying an existing cookie in the `Response.Cookies` collection, the cookie will also appear in `Request.Cookies`, though **the initial cookie will remain there**. Accessing it from there will always yield the first one (the initial one, not the updated one). Usually this is what you want (cookies in `Request` yield values sent by the UA, cookies in `Response` yield values to be sent to the UA). However, since you use `Server.Transfer`, the next page will still see the initial cookie, which is often **not** what you want.